# How does an Atlas V control roll?

Tags: guidance, gimbaled-engines

My understanding is that you want to control roll in a rocket, along with the other directions. An Atlas V has a single RD-180 engine but I didn't see anything about vernier engines. I guess the RD-180 has two combustion chambers and two nozzles, and if those nozzles can gimbal independently that would do it--point them in different directions and the rocket will roll. I suppose that must be the case, otherwise they'll be a little misaligned and you couldn't control it. But I couldn't find anything that explicitly states that.

[image: RD180 model]

Comment: Related: Atlas II used a set of hydrazine thrusters in the interstage for roll control after the vernier rockets were deleted from the first stage.

Answer (score 7):

The RD-180 can gimbal each thrust chamber independently, allowing for roll control.

> Each  Chamber  assembly  is  gimballed  in  two  planes  for  thrust 
>   vector  control.  This  feature  is  implemented through  the 
>   innovative  construction  of  the  gimballing  unit  on  each  hot 
>   oxygen  gasline.  Strains  developed  by  the actuator  for  chamber 
>   gimballing  are  confined  structurally  to  the  engine  elements. 
>   This  is  an  optimal  solution  that provides flight control not only
>   in pitch and yaw, **but also in roll direction**.

(emphasis mine)

From [Incorporation of RD-180 Failure Response Features in the Atlas V Booster Emergency Detection System](https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/supporting-technologies/incorporation-of-rd-180-failure-response-2011.pdf)

Comment: Beat me to the punch; slide 12 of [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/tseitlin/cooperation-rd180-2001) confirms that the RD-180 provides roll control.

Comment: @RussellBorogove looks like a good reference.